# getting the string between two \ sgins

Tags: javascript

How can I get `email` `password` and `confirmPassword` in the below array?

```js
const array = [
     "\"email\" must be a string",
   "\"password\" length must be at least 6 characters long",
   "\"confirmPassword\" must be [ref:password]"
];

// causes the error
console.log(array[0].split('\'))
```

Answer (score 4):

those `'\'` are just an escape to manually insert `"` inside a string delimited by `"`... so in the real string there will be no `\` and so you need the string between the `"`

```js
const array = [
  "\"email\" must be a string",
  "\"password\" length must be at least 6 characters long",
  "\"confirmPassword\" must be [ref:password]"
];

console.log(array[0].split('"'))
```

Answer (score 4):

The back-slash is an escape character for the double-quote.

```js
const array = [
  "\"email\" must be a string",
  "\"password\" length must be at least 6 characters long",
  "\"confirmPassword\" must be [ref:password]"
];

const quoted = array.map(line => line.match(/"(.+)"/)[1]);

console.log(quoted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

This is the same as above, since the escape character is useful only when escaping the quote.

```js
const array = [
  '"email" must be a string',
  '"password" length must be at least 6 characters long',
  '"confirmPassword" must be [ref:password]'
];

const quoted = array.map(line => line.match(/"(.+)"/)[1]);

console.log(quoted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because `\` is the escape character in JavaScript. Therefore if you want to use `\` in a string, you need to double it: `'\\'`. You're basically escaping the `'`, e.g. `"'" === '\''`.

Similar to that, the `\`'s in your array initializing won't actually be part of the string. They're just to make `"` act as a "string character" instead of the `"` "keyword" that'll mark the end of the string.

Try printing the array and you'll see the `\` aren't there.